# How do I add input text from textbox to url?

Tags: python

I'm new to coding and I'm kind of lost atm, I wanted to put whatever is in my textbox to the end of a url.

example

input: 12345
output: https://www.websitehere.net/12345

```
root=Tk()
root.title('Link Opener')
root.iconbitmap('images/buh.ico')
root.geometry("512x512")

def openlink():
    if urlink.get():
        urlink.delete(0,END)

    if entry.get():
    
        urlink.insert(END,text="https://www.websitehere.net/{how do i put here}")

label=Label(root,text="Enter Code", font=("sans", 34))
label.pack(pady=20)

entry=Entry(root,font=("sans,24"))
entry.pack(pady=20)

button=Button(root, text="Open Link", command=openlink, font=("sans",24))
button.pack(pady=20)

nlink=Label(root,text="Link", font=("sans",14))
nlink.pack(pady=50)

urlink=Entry(root, font=("Sans",22), justify=CENTER)
urlink.pack(pady=10)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You concatenate the input text to the URL as:

```py
urlink.insert(END, text="https://www.websitehere.net/" + entry.get())
```